# error when trying to get entity related to entity in webapi 2

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

Models:

```
public class Dog
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }

        public string Color { get; set; }

        public string Race { get; set; }

        public string ChipNumber { get; set; }

        public byte[] Photo { get; set; }



        public virtual ICollection<Record> Records { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

    }

public class Record
    {
        public Record()
        {
            Quota = 1;
        }

        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Time { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Supplier { get; set; }

        public double? Price { get; set; }

        public int Quota { get; set; }

        public string Note { get; set; }



        public virtual Dog Dog { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

WebapiConfig.cs:

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

in webapi calling to 'api/dogs' throws exception:

> {"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The
>   'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/json;
>   charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"$id":"2","Message":"An
>   error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Error getting value from
>   'Records' on
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Dog_2EE5CBDAE5320B6E973C971E716C24610E64BF4CECE05B6719C5876F271BA911'.","ExceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException","StackTrace":"
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object
>   target)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object&
>   memberValue)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter
>   writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object
>   value)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
>   effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
>   effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"$id":"3","Message":"An
>   error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred while
>   executing the command definition. See the inner exception for
>   details.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption
>   mergeOption)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1
>   collection, MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption
>   mergeOption)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Load()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem
>   propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean
>   mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.b__1(TProxy
>   proxy, TItem item)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Dog_2EE5CBDAE5320B6E973C971E716C24610E64BF4CECE05B6719C5876F271BA911.get_Records()\r\n
>   at GetRecords(Object )\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object
>   target)","InnerException":{"$id":"4","Message":"An error has
>   occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"There is already an open DataReader
>   associated with this Command which must be closed
>   first.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand
>   command)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String
>   method, SqlCommand command)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method,
>   Boolean async)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand
>   t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)"}}}}

Comment: I have had similar problems when using nullable datetime values. If this is a get request, could you try setting the DateTime properties to valid datetime values before mapping it to a json object? For example DateTime.Now? Or does this happen whether those properties are null or not?

Comment: i have no other options. these properties must nullable otherwish i cannot execute the `update-database` command

Comment: I understand that, i'm just asking you to do for example Time = DateTime.Now before returning the result just to see if it is successful that way because sometimes the date can be out of range. For example if  instead of being null the date for some reason is  set to 0/0 0000 00:00:00 and that can mess things up.

Comment: ive created a DTO and returned part of the class i need. i used LINQ to initialize the DTO class from the db.
but how do i set a list ?
`from d in db.Dogs
select new DogDTO()
{
  Birthdate = DateTime.Now,
  ChipNumber = d.ChipNumber,
  Color = d.Color,
  Id = d.Id,
  Name = d.Name,
  Photo = d.Photo,
  Race = d.Race,
  UserId = d.User.Id,
  RecordsIDs = ????
};`

Comment: RecordsIds = new List<Record>();

Comment: RecordsIds = from r in d.records selecr r.Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved.

created DTO of DOG and insted of returning a USER and RECORDS inside the DOGDTO it now return UserId and list of RecordIds